# Mousemove problem with classes. If i'm moving the mouse out content disappears

Tags: javascript, object, tabs, mousemove

I have a problem with the menu. Can somebody check?
If I'm moving the mouse out content disappears.
I think there is no problem with classes.

```
class Menu{
    constructor(id){
        this.id = id;

        const linkBlock = document.querySelector(`.navigation__dropdown-block-${this.id}`);
        const menuLink = document.querySelector(`.navigation__link-${this.id}`);
        const menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll(`.navigation__link`);
        const linkBlockA = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__dropdown-block--active')
         
        menuLink.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            linkBlock.classList.add('navigation__dropdown-block--active');
            menuLink.classList.add('navigation__link--active');
        });
        linkBlock.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            linkBlock.classList.add('navigation__dropdown-block--active');
            menuLink.classList.add('navigation__link--active');
        });
        menuLink.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
                linkBlock.classList.remove('navigation__dropdown-block--active');
                menuLink.classList.remove('navigation__link--active');
        });
        linkBlock.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            linkBlock.classList.remove('navigation__dropdown-block--active');
            menuLink.classList.remove('navigation__link--active');
        });
    }
}

const menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__link');
for(let i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++){
    new Menu(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: Please post a runnable codesnippet instead with html and css included. With the code above only we can not help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `If i'm moving the mouse out content disappears.` I have no clue what that means.